# Как организовать одновременное чтение файлов, чьё количество заранее неизвестно?

Tags: java, сортировка

Решил я написать собственный сортировщик больших текстовых файлов (1 Гб+), работает всё шикарно и исправно, кроме одного момента который не даёт мне покоя, ибо нутром чую, что его можно оптимизировать, увеличив скорость сортировки.

Последний этап сортировки включает в себя сортировку слиянием многих уже отсортированных файлов, иногда их число доходит до 100, а то и больше. На данный момент я беру первый файл, и слиянем сортирую со втором. После чего получившийся файл сортирую слиянием с третьим и т.д.

Хотелось бы одновременно читать все файлы построчно, сравнивая их все, тем самым весьма нехило накинуть производительности.

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Вам в выходном файле нужно иметь все строки из всех входных файлов, отсортированные в алфавитном порядке? А зачем для этого читать файлы одновременно, почему нельзя один за другим?

Comment: Суммарный объем всех файлов позволяет держать в памяти всё их содержимое? И пожалуйста, избегайте лирики ("я решил", "всё шикарно"). Задавайте конкретный вопрос, в форме именно вопроса,

Comment: @m.vokhm суммарный объём файлов не позволяет держать их в памяти. Да и сама программа направлена на уменьшение объема используемой памяти.Файлы нудно читать примерно таким образом: считываем первую строку в первом файле, заносим в массив, считываем первую строку во втором файле и заносим в массив и т.д. После считывания всех первых строк, происходит запись наименьшей строки в файл. Вопрос в том, как организовать это последовательное считывание всех файлов.

Comment: Может я всё еще не понял, но почему бы не иметь массив (или список, как удобнее в конкретных обстоятельствах) файлов, потом `в цикле: {` прочитать из каждого из них по одной строке в массив (или в список, опять же), типа `strings[i] = files[i].readLine();`, выбрать нужную строку; и записать ее в файл `}`. Если файлы содержат разное число строк, то соответсвенно скорректировать этот алгоритм, напр. считывать из закончившихся файлов `null` и интерпретировать его как самую большую строку, чтобы не записывать в выходной файл..

Comment: @m.vokhm сложность была именно в создании BufferedReader'ов для каждого текстового файла. Проблему решил созданием собственного класса, работающего с файлом. Для каждого нового файла создаётся экземпляр этого нового класса и заносится в ArrayList, с которым в последствии уже работает сортировщик.

Comment: А вчем сложность создания кучи экземпляров BufferedReader'а?  Почему с собственными классами проще? Я не занудствую, просто интересно -- ситуация небанальная :)